# Tagging documents in SharePoint

Tags: managed-metadata, object-model

Can we tag individual SharePoint documents? If so, how can we read the tags of a document using SharePoint object model?

Answer (score 1):

Create a managed metadata column for your library and then you can be able to tag individual documents.

Comment: how can I read these tags programmatically using object model?

Comment: You can use Taxonomy object model... check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldcontrol.aspx